# Unable to submit jquery mobile search on Android Firefox

Tags: android, firefox, jquery-mobile

Have this header on a jQuery mobile page

```
<div class="ui-grid-a">
<div class="ui-block-a">
    <a href="#start"><img class="logo" src="/Mobile/Images/logo.png" /></a>
</div>
<div class="ui-block-b">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
        <input class="productsearch" placeholder="Sök produkt..." data-type="search" />
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

I listen to both submit and enter keyup with the following code to trigger the search functionality.

```
$(document).on('submit', '.js-mainForm', function() {
    mobileHandler.searchTrigger();
    return false;
});

$(document).on('keyup', '.productsearch', function(event) {

    var keyCode = event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which ? event.which : event.charCode;

    if (keyCode == 13) {
        mobileHandler.searchTrigger();
    }
});
```

The problem Im facing is on Firefox for Android there is no possibility to submit the search. It only shows the Next button on the Android keyboard. In all other android browsers I have tested (Native Gingerbread, Honeycomb and Dolphin browser, and also iPad) the Go button is visible and allows me to submit the form as usual.

How do I do to be able to let Firefox and perhaps other browsers not yet tested that may have the same issue submit the search?

Comment: Have you tested by clicking the 'Enter' button on your device?

Comment: When I test: http://jsfiddle.net/bFGmt/1/ I see an error that `mobileHandler.searchTrigger();` is  not defined.

Comment: The problem is that on Firefox there is no Enter button. The reason that searchTrigger is undefined is that that is a method elsewhere in my code. You could just use alert or something.

Comment: Got that. Will do some testing on FireFox on Android when I get a moment. The function of the search field works on the `onChange` event or `$("input").change(function(){});`. So when a letter is entered, it uses whatever is in the field to perform a filter of a ListView. I would add a Submit Button if possible, cause otherwise you have to have some other interaction with the user, like hitting Enter or Go on the keyboard.